# Matlab: how to sum fields of two equivalent structures?

Tags: matlab, data-structures

I am working in Matlab. I have defined:

```
a(1).x=1;
a(1).y=2;
a(1).z.w=3;

a(2).x=4;
a(2).y=5;
a(2).z.w=6;
```

I am now trying to add the fields in the two structures a(1) and a(2) such that I get:

```
c.x = 5; 
c.y = 7; 
c.z.w = 9;
```

Any idea how I can do this in an elegant way? Note that in the original problem the structures have many more fields (around 50).

Thank you very much in advance!
José

Comment: I see you are using "substructures". Is the deepest level of substructures defined or is any value possible?

Comment: At this point this I have only two levels, e.g., a(1).x and a(1).z.w, but I hoped to find a general way. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: If a more general solution is required I try to adjust my answer. Until then this solution works and it is easy to adjust it for deeper elements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution, for any depth of struct

The code of the script (or MATLAB command)

```
a(1).x=1;
a(1).y=2;
a(1).z.w=3;

a(2).x=4;
a(2).y=5;
a(2).z.w=6;
c=a(1);
c = returnStruct(c, a(2));
%{
you can also sum any amount of structs
for i=2:length(a)
   c=returnStruct(c, a(i));
end
%}
```

with the recursive function

```
function rs = returnStruct(s,a)
fn = fieldnames(s);
for i=1:length(fn)
  if isstruct(s.(fn{i}))
    s.(fn{i}) = returnStruct(s.(fn{i}), a.(fn{i}));
  else
    s.(fn{i}) = s.(fn{i})+a.(fn{i});
  end
end
rs = s;
end
```

I tested it for deeper levels of structs and it worked perfectly. Maybe, you have to adapt it slightly for your case, but this should be the way to go.

Unfortunately, any function like `struct2cell` only converts the first level, so you need something else.

Comment: Thanks a lot Robert! This definitely does it!

Answer (score 0):

If the deepest substructure level is 2 then this code will work:

```
fields=fieldnames(a);
for i=1:numel(fields)
if isstruct(a(1).(fields{i}))
fields2=fieldnames(a(1).(fields{i}));
for j=1:numel(fields2)
a(3).(fields{i}).(fields2{j})= a(1).(fields{i}).(fields2{j})+a(2).(fields{i}).(fields2{j});
end
else
a(3).(fields{i})=a(1).(fields{i})+a(2).(fields{i});
end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Kinkilla! Robert's solution generalizes the case to any number of levels.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a simple recursive solution

```
function r = sumfields(s)
if isstruct(s)
    for f = fieldnames(s).'
        r.(f{1}) = sumfields([s.(f{1})]);
    end
else
    r = sum(s);
end
end
```